# SVG export from Adobe Illustrator generates strange code

Tags: svg, css-position, adobe, adobe-illustrator

In an application that my company is developing, there is a need for symbols generated from Adobe Illustrator to be added as SVG-files. It has been a long development and we already have a library of SVG-files of symbols needed. But now we need a few adjustments on existing symbols, and as I haven't been responsible for creating the old symbols, tried my luck with Adobe Illustrator to export them. But now when I am exporting to SVG, a year later, the code looks different than from before. And the person who made the old ones, a year ago, has left the company...

The only thing we know is that the person used Adobe Illustrator, unknown variant, to make them.
So here is the issue. This is two SVG´s from the same symbol, created in Adobe Illustrator, created using the same export settings (hopefully), probably with different Adobe Illustrator version, but the code looks different. Now you may ask, what is the problem? Well, according to the coders of the application, it matters if the file has relative or absolute coordinates, and the old SVG has relative coordinates but the new has absolute coordinates...

Old SVG file:

[image: Old SVG]

New SVG file:
[image: New SVG]

As you can see, there are several differences within the files.
`<Style>` is different, the old has clean labels of class but the new has some crazy labeling.
And the `<Path class>` is different also with both capital and lower case letters in the code.
And here is the settings in Adobe Illustrator that we use:

[image: AI settings]

You can probably spot more differences of course, but my question is:
How can I generate a SVG file with the clean code from the old SVG I have shown here? What am I doing wrong? And do you need more information?

Thanx in advance
Ulf

I have tried to export the symbols via Adobe Illustrator 28.3, Affinity Design 2.4, Inkcsape 1.3.2.
All of the programs generate completely different code.

Comment: The weird attribution is probably caused by the option "unique object ids". If you select the minify option your paths should be converted to relative commands and shorthands. However Ai tends to mix relative and absolute probably caused by comparing both command values - if absolute produce smaller values output is a mix of both. Inkscape is probably the better option as you can explicitly set the format via Edit/preferences/SVG output. Also it can retain custom attributes like class names or data attributes better (AI tends to remove or rename these)

Comment: Btw. please avoid posting images of your code. Prefer the codesnippet function. Images are welcome if they illustrate for instance a wrong rendering or the desired behavior. Also, wrap  `<tags>` in backticks otherwise the markdown parser will try to interpret these as HTML (the display of your post can be corrupted)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the old SVG was **post-processed** to make everything a `path`

Tell tale sign is the `rect`

[image]

where all settings ended up in the (clear to read) `d-path`

[image]

https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ can do that conversion